# My windows go under panel. I can´t close it

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

Some programs that I open, open under my taskbar. Because of this, I cannot move the program nor close it. I am using Windows 8.1 and I have disabled transparancy, but I still cannot access the close button. See attached screenshot.

How can I fix accessing this program?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the **task manager** and select the file that you want to close. then, click **End task**.

Answer (score 1):

Hover the program on your taskbar so the thumbnail shows up, then rightclick the thumbnail and choose `move`. Now press an arrow key and the window will be snapped to your mousecursor. Move the mouse and you can move it anywhere, allowing you to reach the close button. Click once with the left mouse button to release the snap.

If the `move` button is grayed out, click the 1st item in that menu first, then repeat the above steps if still necessary.